# Snake self-eating optimization

Tags: java

I write my own Snake-game, where Snake is `ArrayList of Points` and I use this method to check self-eating:

```
public void checkSelfEating() {
    for (int i = 1; i < body.size(); i++) {
        if (body.get(i).equals(body.get(0))) {
            sgv.setGameOverState(true);
            sgv.setMessage("Game over!");
            System.out.println("SelfEatingdetected");

        }
    }
}
```

[Video (Started at 35 s.)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dniY76Y1RL8&feature=youtu.be)

[image: VisualVM result]

But it is too slow, and snake do about 5 moves until game is over. Is there a better solution?

Comment: It's surprising that this is slow, given how simple it is. How long is the snake's body?

Comment: At that size a `HashSet` would likely be slower. Are you *totally* sure this code is the slow part? Also, are you calling this method more often than necessary?

Comment: Every move I call this method and check, if game is over.

Comment: [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dniY76Y1RL8&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: I'm not convinced this is the problem, try running your code in jvisualvm and see what it says is slow.

Comment: @VladislavIl'ushin It looks like the problem is in your paint method.

Comment: Paint method takes more time because it is Swing and graphic. BTW, I found, that method return true only when **last** `Point` of `body` **intersected** by **any** another `Point` of `body`

Comment: What I mean is, this method isn't slow, so optimizing it won't solve your problem. If you learn how to use jvisualvm effectively, it should point you to what's slowing your application down. This article: http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1763 gives a general explanation of how to use a profiler.

Comment: @Dan Something wrong in my code, see my previous comment. But code seems correct

Answer (score 3):

Store the body units in a `HashSet` via `add` and `remove` calls.  `O(1)`.  Furthermore if you use a `LinkedHashSet` it will be very easy to manage the head and tail (per comment).

This all being said, while this is the correct data structure and answers your question, I have absolutely no idea why having to do a for loop over a few dozen elements or so is making your program so horribly slow.  I strongly recommend profiling and finding the actual bottleneck as I'm not even sure a hash set will be faster at this scale.

Comment: +1, for this to work his `Point` needs to implement `hashCode()` and `equals()`

Comment: I use `get` method and change value of Array<Points> every move. Easy way?

Comment: You only have to add where the head moved to and remove where the tail left from, 2xO(1).  With some additional handling for what happens while the snake is growing.

Comment: `LinkedHashSet` Takes best off HashSet answer and the comment of Thomas